# Unable to connect to internet through raspberry wifi-to-ethernet bridge

Tags: networking, access-point, bridge

I am trying to set up an access point on a raspberry pi to add wifi to a network. I followed the instructions in [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way), using systemd-networkd.
Here I am targeting the configuration with a network bridge.

```
                               RPi
               wifi   ┌──────bridge──────┐   wired            wan
mobile-phone <.~.~.~> │(wlan0) br0 (eth0)│ <-------> router <-----> INTERNET
            \                   |                   / DHCP-server
           (dhcp              (dhcp           192.168.50.1
        from router)       from router)
```

The bridge seems to work in principle, devices get an IP assigned by the DHCP server and the correct gateway, and I can ping other devices on the wired network from a laptop over wifi, including the Raspberry as well as other computers.

However I can not ping the router from the laptop or reach the internet, and I cannot ping the laptop either from the raspberry or a computer on the wired network.

IP forwarding is enabled.

Output of `ip address`

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:a3:8d:79 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:6a:0a:97:71:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.88.51/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 508sec preferred_lft 508sec
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fea3:8d79/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:6a:0a:97:71:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Edit: I am using a RPi BCM43143 dongle for wifi, with a Raspberry Pi 2B Rev 1.1 running Raspbian 11 (bullseye)

Any help is appreciated to get this to work

Comment: I added the info to the post